# How to do this conditional statement?

Tags: python

I'm doing a generic overloaded operator function that will accept operators +, -, *, /, and **.  The operator comes in as variable "op".  My problem is catching the divide by zero.  The second elif statement is where I'm trying to do this, but it isn't quite correct.  What I'm trying to cover is two things: allow the condition to be true if `self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]` and secondly if the right hand side operand doesn't equal zero when it's division (i.e. `op == '/'` and `operand.list[R][1] != 0`).  If it's false, then it just goes to the else statement.

```
def math(self, op, operand):
     obj = Object()         
    L, R = 0, 0     
        while (L < len(self.list) and R < len(operand.list)):
            if self.list[L][0] > operand.list[R][0]:
                R += 1
            elif self.list[L][0] < operand.list[R][0]:

                L += 1
            elif (self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and op == '*' or op == '**' or op == '+' or op == '-' or (op == '/' and operand.list[R][1] != 0):
                obj.append(self.list[L][0], op(self.list[L][1], operand.list[R][1]))
                L += 1
                R += 1

            else:
                L += 1
                R += 1

    return obj
```

Comment: Got an example usage of this function?

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Have you tried debugging/debug print statements?

Comment: @JohnZwinck this is how it's being called:  obj3 = obj2 + obj1

Comment: @Patashu I expect the condition to be true if self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0] and if the right hand side operator is zero when it is division.  I have tried and the condition won't turn true.

Comment: Just a wag here, but can you try this for your second elif, `elif ((self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and (op in ('*', '**', '+', '-')) or (op == '/' and operand.list[R][1] != 0):`

Comment: Good point @Patashu.  I switched those last two around.

Comment: @sberry, thanks, I gave it a try, but no dice.

Comment: @com I deleted my comment because I had the precedence of and and or backwards. matehat's answer is correct.

Comment: Is `op` a string, or a function? You're comparing it with stings, but immediately afterwards you're calling it. That's not going to work (unless it's an instance with `__call__` and `__eq__` defined in weird ways). Can you show an actual call of the function by the way? `obj2 + obj1` isn't going to run a method named `math` (it will run `__add__` though!).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the middleman: def __add__(self, rhs):
  return self.math(operator.add, rhs)

Comment: @com - it's difficult to debug part of a class where you aren't showing how it's being called or how its expected to work.  Part of your mistake is `def __add__(self, rhs): return self.math(operator.add, rhs)` sets the parameter `op` to be a **function** (`operator.add` - takes two parameters and returns a sum `operator.add(3,4) == 7`).  Thus when you compare the `add` **function** to the string `"+"` its False (`operator.add == "+"` returns False).  Furthermore, generally you can only `append` to a `list` (or list-like object), so does your class define an `append` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to enclose all of your `or` clauses together in parentheses.

Since `and` has higher precedence than `or`, your clause :

```
(self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and op == '*' or op == '**' or op == '+' or op == '-' or (op == '/' and operand.list[R][1] != 0)
```

gets evaluated as

```
((self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and op == '*') or op == '**' or op == '+' or op == '-' or (op == '/' and operand.list[R][1] != 0)
```

So changing it to

```
(self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and (op == '*' or op == '**' or op == '+' or op == '-' or (op == '/' and operand.list[R][1] != 0))
```

should do the trick. Or if you're sure `op` can only be one of those you mentionned:

```
(self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and (op != '/' or operand.list[R][1] != 0)
```

**EDIT** :

From the comments, I strongly believe your operator testing isn't right. If `op` is a built-in function like `div`, here's what you should do:

```
from operator import div, mul, pow, add, sub
```

and in your conditional clause

```
(self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and (op == mul or op == pow or op == add or op == sub or (op == div and operand.list[R][1] != 0))
```

or,

```
(self.list[L][0] == operand.list[R][0]) and (op != div or operand.list[R][1] != 0)
```

Comment: @com Try that last statement I just added at the end.

Comment: Getting closer with that. The operators other than division are working. Still getting a division by zero though.  I checked and the zero still gets past somehow.  I've tried "is not" in place of != and same outcome.

Comment: Looks like the missing link is being able to identify with division.  It along with anything else gets past op != '/'.  It's not identifying '/' as itself.

Comment: You should definitely `print operand.list[R][1].__class__.__name__` to make sure it's a number, `print op` to make sure it's `/` and not \

Comment: Here what came out: print operand.list[R][1].__class__.__name__ = "int".  print op = "<built-in function div>"

Comment: Check out the latest edits, I think it should solve your problem

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your class, you need to explicitly overload the operators: `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, and `__div__` with your custom behaviors.  Your math function won't be called otherwise.

```
class LoudObject(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        """ How to initialize the object with a value """
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        """ How to represent the value when displayed """
        return "LoudObject(%d)" % (self.val,)

    def __add__(self, other):
        print "Look!  Addition!"
        return LoudObject(self.val + other.val)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        print "Subtraction!"
        return LoudObject(self.val - other.val)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print "Multiplication!!!"
        return LoudObject(self.val * other.val)

    def __div__(self, other):
        print "Division!"
        if other.val == 0:
            print "uh-oh, division by zero.  No idea what I should do."
            print "Maybe no one will notice if I return -99999999"
            return LoudObject(-99999999)
        return LoudObject(self.val / other.val)
```

Now you can use it like:

```
In [2]: LoudObject(3) + LoudObject(4)
Look! Addition!
Out[2]: LoudObject(7)

In [3]: LoudObject(3) / LoudObject(4)
Division!
Out[3]: LoudObject(0)

In [4]: LoudObject(3) / LoudObject(4.0)
Division!
Out[4]: LoudObject(0.75)

In [5]: LoudObject(3) / LoudObject(0)
Division!
uh-oh, division by zero.  No idea what I should do.
Maybe no one will notice if I return -99999999
Out[5]: LoudObject(-99999999)
```

Obviously this is a toy example; I wouldn't suggest using a class like this -- and handling division by zero by a large negative sentinel is probably going to lead to problems later on.